# Perl DNA with repeating codons need a script to count and add value

Tags: perl, hash, bioinformatics, counting

I'm just starting perl now and i need a little help. So my problem is i have a dna molecule and i need to find repeating codons in it and print them. Let me give you what have I done till now:

```
$dna ="atatatttaacagattaagagagagagagagttttcccccccccagagatatatatgagaggtata";

for ($i = 0; $i<length ($dna); $i = $i+3) {
    $triplet = substr ($dna,$i,3);
    @triplet = ("$triplet");
    print "@triplet\n";
}
```

and now I just dont know how to do the hash with the counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a loop that not only could count codons on the sequence, but also any DNA word of size k – **a k-mer of length k**. I know you only want to count the codons, but you never know when you will need to do this sort of counting on a sequence again. K-mer counting is a pretty common thing in sequence analysis.  It is always a good idea to write code that solves your problem, **but also works for a bigger scope than it was previously intended** – for the sake of **code reusability**.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#ALWAYS use warnings and strict at the start of every script! It is safer, better,
#and can save you a lot of trouble in debugging your code. Also, declare your
#variables with 'my', so you don't end up with crazy/empty variables 
#all over your code

use warnings;
use strict;

my $dna = 'atatatttaacagattaagagagagagagagttttcccccccccagagatatatatgagaggtata';
my $length = length($dna); #we need the length of the DNA sequence for our loop

my %kmers; #hash with the counts for the codons (or k-mers, your choice)
my $k = 3; #k is the size of the DNA words you want to count. In your case, it is 3.

for(my $i = 0; $i <= $length - $k; $i = $i + 3) {
    my $kmer = substr($dna, $i, $k); #walks over the sequence getting the codons

    #building the hash
    $kmers{$kmer}++; #compact way of saying: if word is new, count =1; 
                                            #if word was already seen, count += 1;

}

#Printing the hash:
while(my ($kmer, $count) = each %kmers) {
    print "$kmer => $count\n";
}
```

**output**

```
ttc => 1
cca => 1
aga => 3
gat => 1
ggt => 1
atg => 1
gag => 3
ata => 3
taa => 1
gtt => 1
tta => 1
ccc => 2
aca => 1
tat => 2
```

To compute **all possible words of length k** on your sequence, the `for` loop would be a little different:

```
for(my $i = 0; $i <= $length - $k; $i++) {
    my $kmer = substr($dna, $i, $k); #walks over the sequence getting the k-mers

    #building the hash
    $kmers{$kmer}++; #compact way of saying: if word is new, count =1; 
                                            #if word was already seen, count += 1;                  
}
```

So, instead of walking **3 bases at time** to count codons (`$i = $i +3`), we would walk through the sequence **one base at a time** (`$i++`). The output for k = 3 is:

```
ttc => 1
agg => 1
cca => 1
att => 2
gat => 2
ttt => 3
ggt => 1
cag => 2
atg => 1
gag => 9
tta => 2
aac => 1
tcc => 1
aag => 1
aga => 10
gta => 1
tga => 1
ata => 6
taa => 2
gtt => 1
ccc => 7
aca => 1
tat => 6
agt => 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of an esoteric function, but I think [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) makes splitting the DNA string into triplets a lot simpler.

You should also `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of *every* Perl program, and declare each variable with `my` as close as possible to its first point of use.

Counting the triplets is just a matter of declaring a hash `%count`, and using all the triplets as keys to increment the count for the appropriate element.

Note that Perl hashes are inherently unordered, so the output is in pseudo-random order. If you want them order by count, or alphabetically, or in the order they appear in the DNA string, then you need to put an additional `sort` on the hash keys.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dna = 'atatatttaacagattaagagagagagagagttttcccccccccagagatatatatgagaggtata';
my @triplets = unpack '(a3)*', $dna;

my %count;
++$count{$_} for @triplets;
printf "%s - %d\n", $_, $count{$_} for keys %count;
```

**output**

```
ttc - 1
cca - 1
aga - 3
gat - 1
ggt - 1
atg - 1
gag - 3
ata - 3
taa - 1
gtt - 1
tta - 1
ccc - 2
aca - 1
tat - 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $dna ="atatatttaacagattaagagagagagagagttttcccccccccagagatatatatgagaggtata";
my @triplets = ( $dna =~ /.{3}/g ); # here it is the trick:
                                    # we use regex to split string in triplets
my %hash = ();

for my $triplet (@triplets) {
  $hash{$triplet}++;
}
```

**Notice that** used regex `/.{3}/g` is "general purpose", since `.` matches any char.
If you know that your dna string is composed only by `a, t, c` and `g` chars, you could use this one instead: `/[atcg]{3}/g` obtaining the same result.

this has been used for output:

```
for my $key (keys %hash) {
  print $key . " =>  " .$hash{$key} ."\n";
}
```

and this was the output:

```
ttc =>  1
cca =>  1
aga =>  3
gat =>  1
ggt =>  1
atg =>  1
gag =>  3
ata =>  3
taa =>  1
gtt =>  1
tta =>  1
ccc =>  2
aca =>  1
tat =>  2
```

Answer (score 0):

the "map" function lets you write this more compactly:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $dna ="atatatttaacagattaagagagagagagagttttcccccccccagagatatatatgagaggtata";
my %hash = ();
map { $hash{$_}++ } unpack('(a3)*',$dna);

print map { ( $_, "\t", $hash{$_}, "\n" ) } sort keys %hash;
```